# how to get first day of month and last day of month using date time in C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class calenderdisp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (!IsPostBack )
        {
            if (ddlweeklist.SelectedItem.Text == "Today")
            {
                txtstart.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                Txtend.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");




            }
        }


    }
    protected void ddlweeklist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlweeklist.SelectedItem.Text == "This Week")
        {
            int st = DayOfWeek.Sunday - dt.DayOfWeek;
            int en = DayOfWeek.Saturday - dt.DayOfWeek;
            txtstart.Text = dt.AddDays(st).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Txtend.Text = dt.AddDays(en).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        }

        if (ddlweeklist.SelectedItem.Text == "Next Week")
        {
            DateTime dt1 = dt.AddDays(7);
            int st = DayOfWeek.Sunday - dt1.DayOfWeek;
            int en = DayOfWeek.Saturday - dt1.DayOfWeek;
            txtstart.Text = dt1.AddDays(st).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Txtend.Text = dt1.AddDays(en).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        }

        if (ddlweeklist.SelectedItem.Text == "Last Week")
        {
            DateTime dt2 = dt.AddDays(-7);
            int st = DayOfWeek.Sunday - dt2.DayOfWeek;
            int en = DayOfWeek.Saturday - dt2.DayOfWeek;
            txtstart.Text = dt2.AddDays(st).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Txtend.Text = dt2.AddDays(en).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        }

        if (ddlweeklist.SelectedItem.Text == "This Month")
        {
            DateTime stmonth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
        DateTime enmnth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));
        txtstart.Text = stmonth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Txtend.Text = enmnth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        txtnodm.Text = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month).ToString();
        Isleap();
        }
    }
}
```

now got the answer...thank u .........but how this can be done using java script as i was very much interested to learn it so please kindly give suggestions to this code to be written in javascript

and i will be glad if u let me know the standard book to be followed to learn java script

Comment: how this code is written in java script.....iam very new to it can anyone suggest me the best links to work over the code using java script

Answer (score 2):

Please try with  the below code snippet.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; //Your Date

DateTime start = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1); //First Date of the month
DateTime end = start.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1); //Last Date of the month

string startDay = start.DayOfWeek.ToString(); //First weekday of the month
string endDay = end.DayOfWeek.ToString(); //Last weekday of the month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = DateTime.Today;
// Start
d.AddDays(-d.Day+1);
// End
d.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-d.Day).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first day is easy with the DateTime constructor.  The last day is one day less than the first day of the next month.

```
public static void FirstAndLastDayOfMonth(DateTime date, out DateTime first, out DateTime last) {
  first = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
  DateTime nextFirst;
  if (first.Month == 12) nextFirst = new DateTime(first.Year + 1, 1, 1);
  else nextFirst = new DateTime(first.Year, first.Month + 1, 1);
  last = nextFirst.AddDays(-1);
}
```

you can also get last day this way:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));
```

or:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

This link may also help you:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/FirstAndLastDay10262007135750PM/FirstAndLastDay.aspx

Comment: Your entire calc for `last` can be replaced by `first.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

To get first day of month:

```
String day = System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
            int date = System.DateTime.Now.Day;
            String fdm = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Convert.ToDouble(date - 1)).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

To get last day of month:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
            var startOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
            var DaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month);
            var lastDay = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, DaysInMonth);
            string lastday = lastDay.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Comment: @clarifier
 use this would really help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(DateTime.Now.Day - 1));
 int lday= DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
 DateTime DTY = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, lday);

 MessageBox.Show("First Day :- "+dt.DayOfWeek.ToString());
 MessageBox.Show("Last Day :-" + DTY.DayOfWeek.ToString());
```